# How do I get the char index of an exact word in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Begin Tran

Declare @Ssql As Varchar(100)
Set @Ssql = 'India is mycountry. I love my country and I am proud of its rich and varied heritage'

Select charindex('country', lower(@Ssql))

RollBack
```

This query returns 12 and not 31.

Okay, now I want the char index of the word `country` [later] and not of the word `country` in `mycountry` [former].

How do I do that ?

Please help.

Comment: Did you try ? Select charindex('country',@Ssql)

Comment: check syntax man u can add another param from where u want 2 start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Begin Tran
Declare @Ssql As Varchar(100)
Set @Ssql = 'India is mycountry. I love my country and'
Select charindex(' country',lower(@Ssql))+1
RollBack
```

or try using the index start postion as

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('country', @Ssql, 14);
```

Comment: That was helpful... a space would certainly distinguish the word. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will give you the last occurrence of the `serachchar`. Using [REVERSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) function many times is detrimental to performance

```
DECLARE @Ssql VARCHAR(500) = 'India is my country. I love my country and I am proud of its rich and varied heritage'
DECLARE @FindChar VARCHAR(7) = 'country'

-- Shows the position of the last occurrence
SELECT LEN(@Ssql) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@Ssql)) AS LastOccuredAt

-- Shows text before last occurrence
SELECT LEFT(@Ssql , LEN(@Ssql ) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@Ssql ))) AS Before

-- Shows text after last occurrence
SELECT RIGHT(@Ssql , CHARINDEX(@FindChar,REVERSE(@Ssql))-1) AS After
```

If your `searchchar` is going to be multiple times and you want the `2nd` occurrence then use as,

```
-- Shows the index of the second occurrence.
SELECT CHARINDEX(@FindChar ,@Ssql,CHARINDEX(@FindChar ,LOWER(@Ssql))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will gives the second word  'country' index...

```
Begin Tran
Declare @Ssql As Varchar(100)
Set @Ssql = 'India is mycountry. I love my country and I am proud of its rich and varied heritage'
Select charindex('country',@Ssql,charindex('country',lower(@Ssql))+1)
RollBack
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,you should be more clear about your requirement.throw 2-3 sample string and explain desire output.

Try this,

```
Declare @Ssql As Varchar(200)
Set @Ssql = 'India is mycountry. I love my country and I am proud of its rich and varied heritage'

Declare @x xml='<n>'+REPLACE(@Ssql,' ','</n><n>')+'</n>'
select * from
(
SELECT cast(a.query('./text()') as varchar) val FROM @X.nodes('/n') AS Z(A)
)t4
where val='country'
```